# Getting a Render not Function Error, when I run this Code Context API and Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

Thanks for taking the time to read this. I have been at this now for a few hours and nearly got it right except now, Im Getting a "TypeError: render is not a function" Error and Can not figure it out, using Context API and Reactjs Please help

I have changed around States and props and back again this is the closest I got it to work

this is my parent file where I pass the UserProvider

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Group from "./Groups";
import JsonData from "../data/export";
import { UserProvider } from "./context/UserContext";

class GroupGrid extends Component {
    render() {
        // console.log(JsonData);
        return (
            <UserProvider value={JsonData}>
                <div className='cards'>
                    <Group />
                </div>
            </UserProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default GroupGrid;
```

this is the child file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import UserContext from "../components/context/UserContext";
import { UserConsumer } from "../components/context/UserContext";

class GroupDetails extends Component {
    static contextType = UserContext;

    componentDidMount() {
        const data = this.context;
        //  console.log(data); // { name: 'Tania', loggedIn: true }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <UserConsumer>
                {this.context.TransportGrid.GROUPS.map((value, index) => (
                    <div key={value.GROUP_ID} className='GroupDetail'>
                        <div className='groupRow1'>
                            <span className='Date_label'>Date:</span>
                            <span className='GroupDate'>
                                {value.GROUP_DATE}
                            </span>

                            <span className='Group_label'>Group No:</span>
                            <span className='GroupID'>{value.GROUP_ID}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className='groupRow2'>
                            <span className='Driver_label'>Driver:</span>
                            <span className='DriverName'>
                                {value.DRIVER_NAME}
                            </span>

                            <span className='Reg_label'>Artic:</span>
                            <span className='VehcileReg'>
                                {value.VEHICLE_REG}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </UserConsumer>
        );
    }
}

export default GroupDetails;
```

and this an example of the JSON it looking at

```
{
    "TransportGrid": {
        "GROUPS": [
            {
                "GROUP_ID": "1234",
                "GROUP_DATE": "20/08/2019",
                "DRIVER_ID": "22",
                "DRIVER_NAME": "JIMMY BLOGGS",
                "VEHICLE_REG": "XSRFDFDDF",
                "START_COUNTRY": "COUNTRY1",
                "END_COUNTRY": "COUNRTY2",
                "MOVEMENTS": [
                    {
```

this is repeated like 180 times ANyone got any idea's?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that your consumer from context API needs to just have a single children element as a function whereas you are having an array of JSX elements as children.

Also since you are using the latest context API you don't need to use the Consumer component, you could simply write your code as

```
class GroupDetails extends Component {
    static contextType = UserContext;

    componentDidMount() {
        const data = this.context;
        //  console.log(data); // { name: 'Tania', loggedIn: true }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {this.context.TransportGrid.GROUPS.map((value, index) => (
                    <div key={value.GROUP_ID} className='GroupDetail'>
                        <div className='groupRow1'>
                            <span className='Date_label'>Date:</span>
                            <span className='GroupDate'>
                                {value.GROUP_DATE}
                            </span>

                            <span className='Group_label'>Group No:</span>
                            <span className='GroupID'>{value.GROUP_ID}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className='groupRow2'>
                            <span className='Driver_label'>Driver:</span>
                            <span className='DriverName'>
                                {value.DRIVER_NAME}
                            </span>

                            <span className='Reg_label'>Artic:</span>
                            <span className='VehcileReg'>
                                {value.VEHICLE_REG}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default GroupDetails;
```